# Android ajax loader

Tags: android, jquery, animation, android-canvas, loader

I'm trying to do a ajax loader but it's not working in Android 1.5, this version doesn't support gif files.

Any sugestion? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the problem using CSS3.

[Pre-loader Animation in CSS3](http://www.webrisorsa.info/ajax-style-pre-loader-animation-in-css3-without-using-images/365/)

[Demo](http://www.nikesh.me/demo/loading.html)

Answer (score 0):

Google is working on it...Apparently. but no luck, even on latest Android platforms